# numpy how to speed up tanh?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

numpy tanh seems much slower than its pytorch equivalence:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np

data=np.random.randn(128,64,32).astype(np.float32)
%timeit torch.tanh(torch.tensor(data))
%timeit np.tanh(data)
```

```py
820 µs ± 24.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
3.89 ms ± 95.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

is there a way to speed up tanh in numpy? Thanks!

Comment: Im not 100% sure but i belive numpy is actually calculating the value of tanh whereas torch is reading it from a lookup table and interpolating it

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eumel! The max error between torch and numpy tanh is ~6e-8 so that's pretty accurate interpolation. Do you know where I can view its code to double check? and where can I find such precomputed lookup table? just curious.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think `numpy` uses trigonometric functions directly from the (C99 and over) `math.h` header. The actual implementation of the trigonometric functions can be system-dependent, though I would imagine it would make use of their associated Taylor series.

Comment: can someone help me show how pytorch implements tanh? I don't how where to look for in its github repo. Thanks!

Comment: If you google `torch github` and use the search in there you should be able to find it

Comment: The `numpy` times for `tanh` are the same as for `sinh`, and not that much more than `sin`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try with `numexpr` as follows:

```
pip install numexpr
```

Then:

```
import numexpr as ne
import numpy as np

data=np.random.randn(128,64,32).astype(np.float32)

resne = ne.evaluate("tanh(data)")
resnp = np.tanh(data)
```

Then check all close:

```
In [16]: np.allclose(resne,resnp)
Out[16]: True
```

And check timings:

```
In [14]: %timeit res = ne.evaluate("tanh(data)")
311 µs ± 1.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [15]: %timeit np.tanh(data)
1.85 ms ± 7.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: That's good to know, thanks Mark! Do you know why is there a huge speed gap?? how come numexpr is much faster?

Comment: It is multithreaded and it precompiles - all magic described here https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/